# What are sensitive permissions in my app?

Tags: android, privacy-policy

I have published simple card-game in android play store. I had used `crashalytics` to taken care of crashes. However, as many of you must have experienced Google Play notifications about "Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement". In that email it was written that

`you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data.`

I have already removed `Firebase analytics` and `Crashalytics` libraries from my app. For now my app has only permission to `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`. Is it "sensitive" permission? What are these 'sensitive' permissions which I can avoid for future development? Just another quick question, is there better alternative to `crashalytics` which will not violate any of these policies?

Comment: it says permissions or `user data`

Comment: i think you not defined a privacy policy. you should define a privacy policy where clear what you going to do with user data

Answer (score 1):

`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` category level is `NORMAL` which might indicate that it's not a sensitive permission like `CAMERA` is.

[image]

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE